# PowerApps - How to write a "Contains" statement

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I have a PowerApps form where I've added some checkboxes, and I want to reference a dropdown field's selection for those checkbox default values.  The issue I'm having is that the choice field is multi-select.  If it weren't I could just go to each checkbox and set its default property to `If(DatacardValue37.Selected.Value = "Advisory", true, false)`.  But this only works if ONLY that choice is selected.

My question is, is there a way to write this default value that will say If(DatacardValue37.Selected.Value *Contains* "Advisory", true, false?  Not sure how to apprach this.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using formula in below format:

```
If("Advisory" in DatacardValue37.Selected.Value, true, false)
```

**Microsoft official documentation**: [Power Apps in Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/operators#in-and-exactin-operators)

Comment: Thank you!  Worked perfectly